# bulk update vs row wise update

Tags: mysql, replication, performance, update, query-performance

I have to update multiple rows (> 100k) satisfying a particular criterion in production environment. Since this query takes much time, it comes in slow query.  someone told me that instead of making a bulk update, we should send update query row wise.

Example-
old query:

```
update table_1 
set column_20 = 'abc' 
where updatedOn > date_sub(now(), interval 1day) and column_19 = 'xyz'
```

New query/method:

```
select auto_increment_id_column  
from table_1 
where updatedOn > date_sub(now(), interval 1day) and column_19 = 'xyz'
```

Now use a **`"for  loop"`**  for all id's extracted from above, then send below query for each id:

```
update table_1 
set column_20 = 'abc' 
where auto_increment_id_column = id_from_for_loop;
```

This method seems to be counter intutive, so, please confirm, if it should be done. Also how it will affect master slave replication.

dbinfo -  mysql and using statement based replication

***Major Update:*** Our DBA recently updated the replication to row based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Update would benefit from the composite `INDEX(column_19, updatedOn)`.

It is almost never faster to use a client loop to do something that can be done in a single SQL statement.

Since you are talking about updating upwards of a million rows, there are other things to discuss...

One should rarely need to update more than a few rows of a table in a batch.  Perhaps `column_20` does not belong in that table; maybe it belongs in a small, maybe one-row, table to avoid this?  Maybe something else.  If you care to describe the semantics of the columns, maybe I can give you more concrete advice.

The reason for the big updating seeming to take "too long" is that it is saving things in case you need to `ROLLBACK`.

But, if you do need to do a massive `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, I recommend [*doing it in chunks*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).  There are notes on the impact on Replication in that document.

Comment: Indexes is being used here. Also agree with you that it should be done in chunks, be it row based replication or statement based replication

Comment: Not two 1-column indexes, one 2-column index.

Comment: Well this is just the prototype of the actual table, by indexes I meant to say required indexes on table were used for update queries. +1 for considering minute details.

Answer (score 0):

Better and effective way is to do this in chunks **"Few large queries are faster than lots of little ones"**.

Check the explain plan(execution plan) for your queries and index them if required.To do it in chunks you can use the LIMIT with your actual query

See my answer for the similar question , it covers the replication scenario as well 
**[Delete data from huge InnoDB table from MySQL Master and Slaves](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56444/4846)**

Comment: Depending on the details, `LIMIT` may not be the best way.